# How to make draggable cells inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

This table is generated dynamically with a JS function. I need it to have droppable cells. The jQuery function won't work on this.

After the cells are generated they belong to the div with `id = "table"`.

How do I access the cells?

```
<body>
<form>
Rows: <input type="text" id="input1"  />
Columns:<input type="text" id="input2" />
<input type="button"  value="Generate" onclick='generateTable();'></input>
</form>
<div id="table"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function generateTable() {
      var rows= document.getElementById("input1").value;
      var columns= document.getElementById("input2").value;

      var r= parseInt(rreshta);
      var c= parseInt(kolona);

      var theader = '<table>\n';
      var tbody = "";

      for(i= 0; i < r; i++){
        tbody += '<tr>';

        for (j = 0; j< c; j++){                 
            tbody += '<td id = "cell" class= "freeCell">';
            tbody += 'Cell: ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>';
        }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

    }

 $( function() {
 $( "#table td" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Edited to try and find a question in amongst the text.

Comment: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin makes it easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$( "#table td" ).draggable();` after the table has been created.

```js
function generateTable() {
      var rows= document.getElementById("input1").value;
      var columns= document.getElementById("input2").value;

      var r= parseInt(rows);
      var c= parseInt(columns);

      var theader = '<table>\n';
      var tbody = "";

      for(i= 0; i < r; i++){
        tbody += '<tr>';

        for (j = 0; j< c; j++){                 
            tbody += '<td id = "cell" class= "freeCell">';
            tbody += 'Cell: ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>';
        }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
   $( "#table td" ).draggable();

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
Rows: <input type="text" id="input1"  />
Columns:<input type="text" id="input2" />
<input type="button"  value="Generate" onclick='generateTable();'></input>
</form>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! It work actually